# Create subprocess box with tikzstyle

Tags: tikz-styles, flow-charts

I found [this guide on making a flowchart with tizk](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/29/tikz-series-pt3.html), but there is no option for the subprocess box.

How could I create a box like this, with the writing in between the two lines on the inside?
[image: Subprocess symbol]

Thanks in advance! :)

**Edit:**
So far, the closest I have gotten is

```
\tikzstyle{subprocess} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30, double distance=

\node (subpro1) [subprocess, below of=start] {Failed subprocess box};
```

but this produces 2 lines on *every* side, whilst I want the double line on only the two vertical sides. It also puts the coloured background only on the inside one whilst I want it to be on the outermost rectangle.

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a minimal example with what you've got so far?

Comment: I've not really gotten very far at all, but I added what I attempted to do. I think it's completely wrong though haha

Comment: Thanks. Could you make it compilable? Maybe with a single example of a node you've got which does work as you want. I am not sure you can do this easily with a node. You might be able to use a pic, but I'm not sure if that would fit.

Comment: @cfr Well someone has given an answer that works now, but would adding a compilable example be a good idea to make it easier for other people who might have the same problem as me and find this question or should I leave it as it is now?

Comment: I think it helps other users, so I would add one. However, I wouldn't do this if your example would invalidate the existing answer for some reason. (I can't think why it would do that, but I guess there might be such cases.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
     \newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ 
subprocess/.style = {rectangle, draw=black, fill=orange!30,
                     minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,inner xsep=3mm,
                     text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
                     align=flush center,
                     path picture={\draw 
    ([xshift =2mm] \ppbb.north west) -- ([xshift= 2mm] \ppbb.south west)
    ([xshift=-2mm] \ppbb.north east) -- ([xshift=-2mm] \ppbb.south east);
                                  },% end of path picture
                    }
                      ]
\node (subpro1) [subprocess] {Failed subprocess box};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum (1):**
Style for `subprocess` you can enclose to `\tikzset` as follows:

```
\tikzset{
    subprocess/.style = {rectangle, draw=black, fill=orange!30,
                         minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, inner xsep=3mm,
                         text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
                         align=flush center,
                         path picture={\draw 
        ([xshift =2mm] \ppbb.north west) -- ([xshift= 2mm] \ppbb.south west)
        ([xshift=-2mm] \ppbb.north east) -- ([xshift=-2mm] \ppbb.south east);
                                      },% end of path picture
                        }
}
```

and put it in preamble of a document.

**Addendum (2):**
In the case, that you wish to have text only on one line, than the code for `subprocess` can be simplified to:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
     \newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}
\tikzset{
subprocess/.style = {rectangle, draw=black, fill=orange!30,
                     minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, inner xsep=3mm,
                     align=flush center,
                     path picture={\draw
    ([xshift =2mm] \ppbb.north west) -- ([xshift= 2mm] \ppbb.south west)
    ([xshift=-2mm] \ppbb.north east) -- ([xshift=-2mm] \ppbb.south east);
                                  },% end of path picture
                    }
        }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (subpro1) [subprocess] {Failed subprocess box};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (3):**
In the case, that you wish to manualy prescribed "minimal/maximal width" of shape, then might the following example can help you:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

     \newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}
\tikzset{
subprocess/.style = {rectangle, draw=black, semithick, fill=orange!30,
                     minimum width=#1, minimum height=1cm, inner xsep=3mm, % <-- changed
                     text width =\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep},
                     align=flush center,
                     path picture={\draw
    ([xshift =2mm] \ppbb.north west) -- ([xshift= 2mm] \ppbb.south west)
    ([xshift=-2mm] \ppbb.north east) -- ([xshift=-2mm] \ppbb.south east);
                                  },% end of path picture
                    },
subprocess/.default = 24mm % <-- added 
        }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (subpro1) [subprocess] {subprocess};% <-- use default width
\node (subpro2) [subprocess=33mm, below=of subpro1] {very long subprocess};% <-- use locally prescribed width
\node (subpro3) [subprocess=44mm, below=of subpro2] {very long subprocess};% <-- use locally prescribed width
\draw   (subpro1) edge[->] (subpro2)
        (subpro2) edge[->] (subpro3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any way that I can place this in the document preamble instead of in each new tikz picture I create? I'm going to have a lot of diagrams, so it'd be better to not have to repeat the same thing several times haha. Also, could you possibly explain what the two lines starting with `xshift` do? I don't think I fully understand...

Comment: @Xhaerithius, of course! enclose definition in `\tikzset{ ... }`. See addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel kinda silly now ¬,¬ `\tikzset` was right there in the documentation--I don't know how I missed it haha. Thanks again for your help! :)

Comment: hmmm one more thing: So if I want the box to stretch to fit longer text, I just need to remove the `text width`, correct? If I do that, is there any way to add some extra padding against the two sides with the lines so that the text is not right up against the lines?

Comment: @Xhaerithius, this can be tricky. `text width` is calculated from `minimum width` and on this way the text limited to bi inside vertical lines. For possible solution see addendum to answer (it will appear soon)